# User data not showing on Html page in Ionic 2 and Firebase 3

Tags: html, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am using a project to get some user data from Firebase.  I want to put that data into a "Profile page".  Everything works except for one problem.  The data doesn't show on the html page until I click on an item in the page, like to edit some data for example.  The data will also show if I click back, then reenter the page.  So it's like the data loads the blank template, but never updates it once the data from Facebook is received.  Any suggestions?  Here is some of the code from the page.

profile.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button item-left icon-right (click)="logOut()">
        <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
        Logout
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Personal Information
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item (click)="updateName()">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-50>
            Name
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col *ngIf="userProfile?.firstName || userProfile?.lastName">
            {{userProfile?.firstName}} {{userProfile?.lastName}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="placeholder-profile" *ngIf="!userProfile?.firstName">
            <span>
              Tap here to edit.
            </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="dob-label">Date of Birth</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM D, YYYY" pickerFormat="D MMM YYYY"
        [(ngModel)]="birthDate" (ionChange)="updateDOB(birthDate)"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item (click)="updateEmail()">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-50>
            Email
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-50 *ngIf="userProfile?.email">
            {{userProfile?.email}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="placeholder-profile" *ngIf="!userProfile?.email">
            <span>
              Tap here to edit.
            </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item (click)="updatePassword()">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-50>
            Password
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="placeholder-profile">
            <span>
              Tap here to edit.
            </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the code from the profile.ts page

```
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileData } from '../../providers/profile-data';
import { AuthData } from '../../providers/auth-data';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {
  public userProfile: any;
  public birthDate: string;
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public profileData: ProfileData,
    public authData: AuthData, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }


  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.profileData.getUserProfile().on('value', (data) => {
      this.userProfile = data.val();
      this.birthDate = this.userProfile.birthDate;
    });
  }
```

I also tried wrapping it in an NgZone object as suggested by others, which looks like this:

```
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileData } from '../../providers/profile-data';
import { AuthData } from '../../providers/auth-data';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {
  public userProfile: any;
  public birthDate: string;
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public profileData: ProfileData,
    public authData: AuthData, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.zone = new NgZone({});

    this.zone.run(() => {
      //Your promise code
      this.profileData.getUserProfile().on('value', (data) => {
        this.userProfile = data.val();
        this.birthDate = this.userProfile.birthDate;
      });
    });

  }
```

None of this seems to work.  The data is there, it just doesn't show until I click on an item/UI object, then it populates correctly.  Help!

Comment: Hope your best friend here is `Angularfire2` `observable()`.

Comment: How do I implement that in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below.Hope code is self-explanatory.If you have any question, please comment below.

[**How to install Angularfire2?**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

*ProfileData.ts*

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileData {

     constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}

     getUserProfile(data: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
        return this.af.database.object(`path-to-your-firebase-object`);
      }
}
```

*YourComponent.ts*

```
public profile: any;

 constructor(public profileData: ProfileData) {

    this.profileData.getUserProfile(your-user-id).subscribe(profileSnap => {
      this.profile= profileSnap ;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your help.  I will implement this and see if I can get it to work